# Running header missing from my pdf file

Tags: fancyhdr, afterpage

Here is a Latex code of a journal's template. While the accompanying pdf in the journal's site shows a running header in both the odd and the even pages, when I execute the same file, I do not get a running header in the even pages. More specifically, the command,

```
\afterpage{\rhead[]{\thepage} \chead[\small A.B. First and C.D.         
Second Author]{\small  Short title} \lhead[\thepage]{} }
```

seems to give no output. I had emailed a few people and when they run it on their computer, the output seems to be fine. They suggested me to update my LaTeX version. I am currently using Tex Live version 2021.
I might be missing something obvious but I have been stuck for a very long time.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{rotate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}  %

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\textheight185mm
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
\def\t{\hspace{-6mm}{\bf .}\hspace{3mm}}
\def\bt{\hspace{-2mm}{\bf .}\hspace{2mm}}
\def\hs{\hspace*{0.56cm}}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in} \addtolength{\hoffset}{3.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12.5cm} \setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{3cm}
\setcounter{page}{1}                                       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  starting page
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{} \fancyhead[CO]{\small
Quasigroups~and~Related~Systems ~{\bf 30}~(2022), $xx - yy$}  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{\rhead[]{\thepage} \chead[\small A.B. First and C.D.         %%%%%%%%% complete
Second Author]{\small  Short title} \lhead[\thepage]{} }                  %%%%%%%%% complete

\begin{center}
\vspace*{2pt}
{\Large \textbf{The full title of the paper}}\\[3mm]
{\Large\textbf{continue or delete this line}}\\[26pt]
{\large \textsf{\emph{Author(s) with the full first name }}}
\\[26pt]
\end{center}
\textbf{Abstract.} {\footnotesize We describe }

\footnote{\textsf{2010 Mathematics Subject Classification:} .....
}
\footnote{\textsf{Keywords:} .... }

\section*{\centerline{1. Introduction}}\setcounter{section}{1}

A groupoid is \emph{medial} if it satisfies the identity $wx\cdot
yz = wy\cdot xz$. A groupoid is \emph{trimedial} if every
subgroupoid generated by $3$ elements is medial.

In \cite{kepka1} it is proved that a quasigroup satisfying the
following three identities must be trimedial.
\begin{eqnarray}
xx\cdot yz &=& xy\cdot xz \\
yz\cdot xx &=& yx\cdot zx \\
(x\cdot xx)\cdot uv &=& xu \cdot (xx\cdot v)
\end{eqnarray}

\noindent The converse is trivial, and so these three identities
characterize trimedial quasigroups. Here, we show that, in fact,
(2) and (3) are sufficient to characterize this variety (as a
subvariety of the variety of quasigroups).

\section*{\centerline{2. Medial quasigroups}}\setcounter{section}{2}

 \begin{theorem}\label{T1} Let $G$ be a quasigroup...
 \end{theorem}


\begin{proof} If $G$ is a quasigroup...
\end{proof}

\begin{corollary} Let $G$ be a quasigroup...
\end{corollary}

\begin{remark} It is only an example. The
paper accepted for publication in our journal must be prepared in
Latex, Amstex or similar style preserving the general convention
presented in this form.
\end{remark}

\small
\begin{thebibliography}{20}
\bibitem{kepka1}
{\bf T. Kepka}, {\em Structure of triabelian quasigroups},
Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. \textbf{17} (1976), no. $2$,
$229-240$.

\end{thebibliography}

\noindent
\footnotesize{Full address, for example \\
         Faculty of Pure and Applied Mathematics\\
         Wroclaw University of Sience and Technology\\
         Wyb. Wyspianskiego 27 \\
         50-370 Wroc{\l}aw\\
         Poland\\
E-mail: abc.edu }

\newpage
xxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't clear what you are intending to do here, setting \rhead inside \afterpage doesn't look right at all, I doubt you want afterpage at all here. Note also that `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex for almost 30 years.

Comment: Exactly! The \afterpage was creating trouble. It is actually a template issued by the journal's site so I didn't tweak the code fearing it might change some other mandatory formatting style. I just tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before \begin{document} delete all your configuration for h/f and write this code:

```
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyfoot{} 
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[CO]{\small Quasigroups~and~Related~Systems ~{\bfseries 30}~(2022), $xx - yy$} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\small A.B. First and C.D.Second Author} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\small Short title} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

You have the desired result for odd AND even pages:
[image]

EDIT: In any case I add the whole MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{rotate}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
%\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{afterpage}  %

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\textheight185mm
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
\def\t{\hspace{-6mm}{\bf .}\hspace{3mm}}
\def\bt{\hspace{-2mm}{\bf .}\hspace{2mm}}
\def\hs{\hspace*{0.56cm}}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in} \addtolength{\hoffset}{3.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12.5cm} \setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{3cm}
\setcounter{page}{1}    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  starting page

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyfoot{} 
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[CO]{\small Quasigroups~and~Related~Systems ~{\bfseries 30}~(2022), $xx - yy$} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\small A.B. First and C.D.Second Author} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\small Short title} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{2pt}
        {\Large \textbf{The full title of the paper}}\\[3mm]
        {\Large\textbf{continue or delete this line}}\\[26pt]
        {\large \textsf{\emph{Author(s) with the full first name }}}
        \\[26pt]
    \end{center}
    \textbf{Abstract.} {\footnotesize We describe }
    
    \footnote{\textsf{2010 Mathematics Subject Classification:} .....
    }
    \footnote{\textsf{Keywords:} .... }
    
    \section*{\centerline{1. Introduction}}\setcounter{section}{1}
    
    A groupoid is \emph{medial} if it satisfies the identity $wx\cdot
    yz = wy\cdot xz$. A groupoid is \emph{trimedial} if every
    subgroupoid generated by $3$ elements is medial.
    
    In \cite{kepka1} it is proved that a quasigroup satisfying the
    following three identities must be trimedial.
    \begin{eqnarray}
        xx\cdot yz &=& xy\cdot xz \\
        yz\cdot xx &=& yx\cdot zx \\
        (x\cdot xx)\cdot uv &=& xu \cdot (xx\cdot v)
    \end{eqnarray}
    
    \noindent The converse is trivial, and so these three identities
    characterize trimedial quasigroups. Here, we show that, in fact,
    (2) and (3) are sufficient to characterize this variety (as a
    subvariety of the variety of quasigroups).
    
    \section*{\centerline{2. Medial quasigroups}}\setcounter{section}{2}
    
    \begin{theorem}\label{T1} Let $G$ be a quasigroup...
    \end{theorem}
    
    
    \begin{proof} If $G$ is a quasigroup...
    \end{proof}
    
    \begin{corollary} Let $G$ be a quasigroup...
    \end{corollary}
    
    \begin{remark} It is only an example. The
        paper accepted for publication in our journal must be prepared in
        Latex, Amstex or similar style preserving the general convention
        presented in this form.
    \end{remark}
    
    \small
    \begin{thebibliography}{20}
        \bibitem{kepka1}
        {\bf T. Kepka}, {\em Structure of triabelian quasigroups},
        Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. \textbf{17} (1976), no. $2$,
        $229-240$.
        
    \end{thebibliography}
    
    \noindent
    \footnotesize{Full address, for example \\
        Faculty of Pure and Applied Mathematics\\
        Wroclaw University of Sience and Technology\\
        Wyb. Wyspianskiego 27 \\
        50-370 Wroc{\l}aw\\
        Poland\\
        E-mail: abc.edu }
    
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried running this code and it finally work! Thank you.